Yahweh can be a pagan god but Al-Lah cannot? Double Standard in favour of Islamic god on Christianity:SE
This site claim to be secular, not Christian to avoid dogmatic bias to defend free and open thoughts. Recently, I was forced to delete my references of remotely mentioning that al-Lah is a moon god, a mainstream Evangelical view about Islamic god which associates him as the Hubal aka Bal as shown by the popular Christian sites and apologists. It was in that question Did Arab Christians use the word "Allah" before Islam? I made no insult or used a bad tone to mention some arguments to show Allah is not same as al ilah, by showing the name YaSin. My answer was deleted, and I was banned for a week without any reason, with defamatory abusive accusations of using abusive behaviour. Despite deleting the reference to YaSin, my answer has not been reinstated, it's still a deleted answer and the mods refuse to undelete it, in what appears to be an extreme sensitivity or insecurity in favour of Islam.
Interestingly, the questions that discuss the theory of Yahweh being a pagan god are [rightfully] allowed here. Is it true that Yahweh was part of a polytheistic religion?. Although, one member user22071 who affirmed the view that Yhwh was a pagan deity got his account deleted due to what seems to be generally caused by bullying and harassment by "the secular". Though, I see no reason to oppose and censor such question and answers which genuinely want to study various views and questions from an academic perspective, despite being a Christian. Also see on History.SE Was Yahweh a god in a possible Edomite Pantheon?
Now the questions arise: Does the secular moderation really favours Islam to an extreme extent, or is this a new policy they forgot to inform us? Is that bias for Islam exist only on Christianity.SE and not History.SE, why? If such overprotective bias exists, then the Islam tags are useless, and you have to reject all topics that come from Islamic background. Even though there have been some Muslim seekers recently asking genuine questions about Mahdi and Jesus in the end times topic, which have been strongly discouraged by members.
If someone asks a question related to Islamic god here from a Christian perspective, are we forced to comply with Islamic mainstream view to support Islamic beliefs which does not allow scholars to go against standard Islamic narrative due to death penalty. To which extent do we have to affirm Islamic views here; if the view that allah is not same as al-ilah is allowed, then my answer should be restored.

Topics discussing Hindu gods being demons allowed without anyone's blood boiling. Are hindus being marginalized in ChristianitySE? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/are-pagan-gods-possessed-by-demon-how-can-jesus-help-with-influence-from-pagan

distinguo It's not the moderators, it's the community managers. The only thing I wasn't a big fan of in your original post was linking to a self-proclaimed scholar on youtube.   But we set the bar pretty low for scholarship when it comes to saying something is Not An Answer.   To be fair though, if you're gonna use wikipedia for one part of your answer, but leave out the part in wikipedia that said the theory was discredited, you're being a little disingenuous.
I read your edit and I would undelete, but I kinda gotta run it by the CM's before because of how hard they (singular they, probably - I don't think it's a conspiracy) came down on you and I don't want to get you rebanned because it is usually longer.
The one thing I would add to your answer is a closing statement because I don't really see how all the quotes and stuff tie together to make an answer.
In any event, that stuff you posted boils my blood - I would not let my kids read it,  it's probably just anti-Christian, anti-semetic, Marxist propoganda.
However, I read enough Chesterton to be skeptical of both your etymological reduction (read the opening few chapters of the Flying Inn for a good explanation of the Turkish roots of all the English Pubs) and all that garbage on history.se (Read the first half of The Everlasting Man - for GK's take down of H.G. Wells' outline of history and what he had to say about "the old man" that 1900's scientists posited.  The joy he had in noting that the Illiad was not composed by Homer, but someone else named Homer or that because Shakespeare kept horses, he might have kept pigs and therefore bacon could have truly written Shakespeare.
He also points out an astute point that most of the historical record is garbage written by the least reliable person. So keep in mind, this site is about Christian Doctrine which is much more important and much more true than history.

If youre referring to my answer about Allah not being al-ilah which I used Islamic and other arabic sources, not Wiki (moreover wiki is not known to be Marxist in certain biases, there's no reason to be consistently blindly follow it on everything as a standard), that it makes your blood boils, then you are proving you are not fit to be a mod here if you're too emotionally sensitive for particular topics of disagreement to characterise things you disagree like that. The Community managers need to explain their bias in favour of Islam; if mods allowed it then its an internal dispute with them

Why has my answer not undeleted yet? I read your answer where you quote Hilare's book describing Muhammad as pagan chief heresiarch, and you described how you've been convinced that Islam has the same God as Jews n Xians, & Islam a heresy of Catholicism, which may've caused your blood boil if someone rejects your belief; though your ans would boil the blood of muslims or some other Xians, if they have similar intolerant nature as yours.
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/christian-view-of-why-there-are-so-many-similarities-between-quran-and-bible/11685#11685

@Michael16 Even if I disagree, I don't undo what CM's have done without their consent, just like it's not generally appropriate for users to undo what mods do (hint: if you don't want to get suspended in the future let us edit your posts and ask about it on meta or chat before rolling back a moderator's change).  Why not ping Bella Blue again on your original post?
